# OAuth authentication with angular fire using my own login form

Tags: angular, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Using angular fire 2, I am looking at how to authenticate with a google account.
This [simple example](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) works. Login action is done like follows

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

This is opens a popup to the google login form but I would like to use my own form.

Is there a way to authenticate using OAuth with a homemade form, not the automatic popup ?

Comment: Did you read the section on [Handling the sign in flow manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually)? That sounds like what you're asking for. Once you have the OAuth token from the third party, just call signInWithCredential(). (But I don't imagine most OAuth providers want you messing with the auth forms. That's sort of the point of OAuth--deferring the auth validation to a trusted third party, i.e. not you)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer